# Keep Navigation Drawer Open

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

I'm building an app where I want to show some additional information in the navigation drawer but  after clicking inside of the navigation drawer it closes by default and I would like it to remain open till the user click outside the navigation drawer or presses the back button

Is this possible? And how do I implement it ? If not how else can I implement it without using the navigation view

I have tried using: mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
In my onCreate and onNavigationItemSelected  ...Using it on the onCreate opens up the navigation drawer by default leaving me unable to close it

This is my drawer listener code;

```
DrawerLayout   drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
```

Comment: post your listener code, please.

Comment: yes, please post your code

Comment: Why I downvote: You have ignored requests to see your code. SO requests that the person asking the question provide a MVC.  Not Posting your code makes it difficult to provide an answer that would satisfy your requirements. Additionally, a lot of guessing, a lot of back and forth trying to provide a satisfying solution. If you edit your question and post your code, then I will change my vote.

Comment: You're getting it wrong @Brans my drawer listener is working  fine . What I'm trying to do is to prevent the navigation drawer from closing when the user interacts with it .Unless the user touches outside the drawer or presses the back button

Comment: That is exactly what I was doing before so it didn't help if you read my comment to his reply. I'm using the default Navigation drawer layout which auto generates the drawer listener

Comment: Edit your post to show the `onNavigationItemSelected()` method.  That is where the code will be that generally handles closing the menu.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout; // Global variable

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


        drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START); // Use this line of code where you want to keep open the drawerLayout.
```

If you still have problem to understand please let me know.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to override the default closing of the navigation drawer when a touch input is made within the navigation drawer

Comment: **drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);**                      You can close navigation drawer by using this line of code.