# My Navigation Drawer closes whenever i click some item on it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

How do I make it so when I click on the menu it does something (in this case write "click")? For some reason it's not working. I followed a youtube video for this , I'm new to android studio. Thank you in advance. Also how do i bypass this "mostly code" error. when I have not more to explain.

```
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.open_drawer,R.string.close_drawer);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    drawerToggle.syncState();

    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


}
```

The OnClick part

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.nav_new_purchase:

                Toast.makeText(this,"CLICK",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_active_purchase:
                //TODO

            case R.id.nav_old_purchase:
                //TODO
        }
        return false;
    }
```

XML file with the  (main_activity.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawer">

    <include

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/app_toolbar"/>
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/add_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:foreground="@drawable/ic_action_add"
            app:backgroundTint="#00FF00"
            app:fabCustomSize="200dp"
            app:fabSize="auto"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:text="@string/add"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add_button" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to post the layout XML file with the `<DrawerLayout>`.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52897214/keep-navigation-drawer-open)

Comment: Move the `<NavigationView>` to after the `<ConstraintLayout>`. The drawer in a `<DrawerLayout>` must be listed last in order to work correctly. Also, you really should have only one main content `View`. That is, you should somehow combine that `<include>` and `<ConstraintLayout>` into one. Otherwise, one of them is going to completely cover the other one, and you will likely have problems interacting with the one in back.

Answer (score -1):

You check follow:

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        //add this line
        Toast.makeText(this,"WORK",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        switch (menuItem.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.nav_new_purchase:

                Toast.makeText(this,"nav_new_purchase",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_active_purchase:
                Toast.makeText(this,"nav_new_purchase",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_old_purchase:
                Toast.makeText(this,"nav_new_purchase",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(this,"Not found menu id",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

If will show "WORK", you code work. Also, There is shown clicked id or  "Not found menu id". If will show "Not found menu id", you check wrong menu id.

Comment: The "WORK" part is not working

Answer (score -1):

drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START) add this code last line click listener